# Local Object became nil before returning completion block - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, completionhandler, retain-cycle

I have an object that declared inside a function. this object makes a function call which has a completion block. the function executes properly.

This function makes a network call (which is in another class). after getting the result from network call, I am making a check to see if the class is still in memory (using weakSelf and strongSelf)

during this check, it shows, the self is nil.

I know if I use a class method or property variable I can resolve this. but is there any way to retain this object (which declared inside a function).
I tried __strong and __block with the object, but not working.

Here is my code

```
@implementation AViewController {
        -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
            [super viewWillAppear:animated];
            [self methodA];
        }
        -(void)methodA {
            LocalClass *object = [LocalClass alloc] init];
            [object aMethodWithCompletionBlock:^(NSDictionay *result) {

            }];

        }
    }
    @implementation LocalClass {
        - (void)aMethodWithCompletionBlock:(void (^)(NSDictionay *result))completionHandler {

            __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
            [NetworkClass methodToMakeRESTRequestOnComplete:^(NSDictionay *someResult) {
                __strong typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
            if(!strongSelf) { // this check fails as strongSelf is nil
                return;
            }

            //some code execution
            if (completionHandler != nil) {
                completionHandler(someModifiedResult);
            }
            }];
        }
    }
```

Comment: @matt if I move ` __strong typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf; ` up before the method call, then its not nil. and the block is called. But is it a proper way..??

Comment: I mean adding this strong self and weak self is to avoid any retain cycle or avoid executing on a nil object right..? if I move up before the method call which is same as not giving a weak and strong check.. is that correct..?

Comment: so if somehow, the AViewController deallocated and removed from memory, this method still pass the completion handler back to the controller,.. right...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know if I use a class method or property variable I can resolve this. but is there any way to retain this object (which declared inside a function). I tried `__strong` and `__block` with the object, but not working.

Your code is trying to solve a problem which doesn't exist and it doing so creates one.

The purpose of the `weakSelf`/`strongSelf` pattern it to deal with *harmful* reference cycles (not all reference cycles are harmful, indeed some are useful). You should only use it if you have identified you that there is such a harmful cycle.

Let's look at your code without any `weakSelf`/`strongSelf` dance:

```
 1 @implementation AViewController
 2 {
 3    -(void)methodA
 4    {  LocalClass *object = [LocalClass alloc] init];
 5       [object aMethodWithCompletionBlock:^(NSDictionay *result) { ... }];
 6    }
 7 }
 8 
 9 @implementation LocalClass
10 {
11    - (void)aMethodWithCompletionBlock:(void (^)(NSDictionay *result))completionHandler
12    {  [NetworkClass methodToMakeRESTRequestOnComplete:^(NSDictionay *someResult)
13       {
14          if (!self)
15             return;
16 
17          //some code execution
18          if (completionHandler != nil)
19             completionHandler(someModifiedResult);
20       }];
21    }
22 }
```

Now what will happen when you have an instance of `AViewController` and invoke `methodA`?

1. At line 3 a new instance of `LocalClass` is created and a reference to it stored in `object`. The type of `object` is implicitly `__strong LocalClass *` and so the new instance has a strong reference to it and will stay alive.
2. At line 5 the method `aMethodWithCompletionBlock:` is called on the object referenced by `object` passing it a closure. *Note that neither `methodA` or the instance of `AViewController` it is being called for keep a reference to this closure, it is just passed to the method. Therefore after the call there is no possibility of a reference cycle between a local variable belonging to `methodA` or an instance variable belonging to `AViewController` and the closure.*
3. At line 12 method `methodToMakeRESTRequestOnComplete:` of `NetworkClass` is called passing it a closure

   - This closure references `self` so it contains a strong reference back to the instance of `LocalClass` on which `aMethodWithCompletionBlock:` was called
   - This is the *same* instance of `LocalClass` that was created at Line 3 and so there are now two strong references to that object.
   - The closure also contains a strong reference to the block referenced by the parameter `completionHandler`
4. At line 20 `methodToMakeRESTRequestOnComplete:` returns, as the passed block is a completion block it is unlikely to have been called yet. So at this point `NetworkClass` has a reference to that completion block, and the completion block has a reference to the `LocalClass` instance.
5. At line 21 `aMethodWithCompletionBlock:` returns. The instance of `LocalClass` it was called on has kept no references to the parameter `completionHandler`.
6. At line 6 `methodA` returns. This destroys its local variable `object` which drops the strong reference to the `LocalClass` instance it referenced. The system can *consider* destroying that instance at this point, **however** as `NetworkClass` has a strong reference to a completion block which in turn has a strong reference to this same `LocalClass` instance it is still needed and not destroyed.
7. At some future time line 14 is reached after `NetworkClass` invokes the block reference it kept. The `self` variable contains a strong reference to the `LocalClass` instance originally created at line 4, that instance therefore still exists and all is well with the world.
8. At line 20 the completion block returns. If at this point `NetworkClass` drops its strong reference to the block the block can be (probably – assuming there are no other strong references to it) destroyed. That destruction removes the strong references the block has to the objects referenced by its `self` and `completionHandler` and so those objects can also (probably...) be destroyed and the objected originally created at line 4 bites the dust.

There are no harmful cycles, no need for any weak references to manage them.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Makes sense